# OpenCart 3.x new information pages not loading and produces Apache Error

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

ok, so I have inherited the responsibility of fixing some issues with a current OpenCart system that is running version 3.0.2.0 with SEO URLs. Now I have worked with OpenCart since version 1 and I have tried all the common solutions and checked all the common issues around information pages and their failure to load.
[DEV OPENCART SITE](http://test2.statesupplyprops.com)
There are several information pages already and they work about, as seen on and contact. However, the information page for forms results in a page not found error.

So I went into the admin area went to the information page and checked to make sure that it was on, the SEO keyword setting was correct and then made sure it had content. I even took the step of creating another information page and it too ended in the same result.

I checked the htaccess file that is fine its contents are here below

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent directory listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have also confirmed that mod_rewrite is actually installed and set up on the hosting account, even though the others worked as a Programmer I wanted to be extra sure!

I have cleared the cache and even restarted the instance to make sure nothing was being held on too since I didn't know how long it had been running. Mostly because they started development last year and already been through several developers.

I then dug through all of the OpenCart logs that yielded no handy information at all about the situation. So I turned to the actual PHP logs and found the oddest error, as you can see from below it is referencing the forms SEO URL at the end of the error.

```
    AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/vhosts/statesupplyprops.com/test2.statesupplyprops.com/image/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm,index.shtml) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://test2.statesupplyprops.com/forms
```

Comment: If you disable **SEO URLs**, everything works?

Comment: I have actually back tracked it to the theme or megamenu itself. The theme has it built in and there is another megamenu plugin installed. But that still doesn't explain why about, as seen in and contact information pages work but not forms. No matter what I do I cannot get it to produce an error just the message "The page you requested cannot be found!" under the slider.